# регулярное выражение для 4 или 6 значного pin кода

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if re.search('^\d{4}$|^\d{6}$', pin):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

требуется чтоб выражение не находило "граничные" случаи например 098765' также '5862

upd: требуется найти **исключительно** 4 или 6 цифр и ничего кроме этого

Comment: По какому правилу определяются граничные случаи?

Comment: @becouse в вопросе я привел примеры. я сам не сильно то понимаю что это значит. суть в том чтоб регулярка не работала на приведенные мною примеры

Comment: Я уточняю, что только эти два не подходят? Потому что нужно описать шаблон и потом составить выражение.

Comment: @becouse где в начале или в конце есть символ ```'```

Comment: Т. Е. На цифры нет ограничения? Из приведённых условий это не очевидно

Comment: @becouse 4 или 6 цифр и ничего кроме них

Comment: Цифры лучше проверять `[0-9]` потому что `\d` может так же захватывать + и -. А условие... попробуйте `^(([0-9]{4,4})|([0-9]{6,6}))$`

Comment: @becouse это задачка в codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/55f8a9c06c018a0d6e000132/train/python ```[0-9]``` не помагло

Comment: @nick_n_a а зачем повтор в ``{6,6}``? ``{6}`` достаточно. И не указано, что вся строчка состоит только из пинкода, т.е. символы ^ и $ противоречат условиям.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0Rc6Ec/2 - попробуйте этот regexp `^(?!^[0-9]{5}$)[0-9]{4,6}$`

Comment: `pin.isdecimal() and len(pin) in {4, 6}` можно и вообще без регулярок, ну это так, мысли вслух, кому интересно

Comment: Тогда вабанк -  можно найти не цифру, а потом цифру `[^0-9]+[0-9]{4}[^0-9]+`  затем снова нецифру OR второй довесок.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое регулярное выражение [работает](https://regex101.com/r/6gBNsU/1)

```
^([0-9]{4})$|^([0-9]{6})$
```

Пример кода

```
import re

regex = r"^([0-9]{4})$|^([0-9]{6})$"

test_str = ("012345\n"
    "1234\n"
    "'1234\n"
    "j3322\n"
    "2333'")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Работает, только если пин-код - единственное слово в строке. Этого по условиям не дано.

Comment: @Эникейщик там много чего не дано по условию. Задача читается как задача валидации входной строки на бытие допустимым пин-кодом.

Comment: этот вариант так же прошел проверку, возможно просто kata багнутая ибо и мой варик и ваш проходят проверку локально

Comment: этот вариант так же прошел проверку, возможно просто kata багнутая ибо и мой варик и ваш проходят проверку локально

Comment: Всякие случаи бывают